# PyQt QAction connecting to Exit popup

Tags: python, pyqt, qaction

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import iconresource

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(770, 630)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(4)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 361, 371))
        self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableView"))
        self.plainTextEdit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 30, 321, 371))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 430, 361, 131))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 450, 241, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Arial"))
        font.setPointSize(17)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icon/icon/computer.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.actionConnect = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icon/icon/display.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionConnect.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionConnect.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionConnect"))

        self.actionImport = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icon/icon/folder-open.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionImport.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionImport.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionImport"))

        self.actionExport = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icon/icon/save.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionExport.setIcon(icon3)
        self.actionExport.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExport"))

        self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icon/icon/cancel.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionExit.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionExit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExit"))
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.programExit)

        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionConnect)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionImport)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionExport)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionExit)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "AVMT Log Connecter", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START", None))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar", None))
        self.actionConnect.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect", None))
        self.actionImport.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Import", None))
        self.actionExport.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Export", None))
        self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit", None))

    def programExit(self):
        quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message', quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to actionExit -> programExit() but this code is not working
Error : TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call
please solve this problem

Comment: Consider [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your code raises following error: `ImportError: No module named iconresource`.

Comment: that is external icon py file. except that and retry

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message continues:

```
...
QMessageBox.question(QWidget, QString, QString, QMessageBox.StandardButtons 
buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton):
argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
...
```

Your `self` is not a `QWidget` but a `Ui_MainWindow`. Change `self` to `self.centralwidget` and it should work.

```
def programExit(self):
    quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self.centralwidget, 'Message', quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass
```